# MongoDB Atlas connection working but not displaying data correctly

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, atlas

I want to send sign-up form data to the MongoDB Atlas. The connection is successful and data is sending to the database but its not correct. I have attatched screenshot of data which I have received and screenshot of data which I wants to send.

[image: Screenshot of MongoDB Atlas database]

[image: Screenshot of required data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just edited this part of code in record.js file and the problem solved! :)

[image: Problem Solved!]